# Synchronize 4GB of files

Tags: dropbox, sync

Is there any service with Linux client that can deal with synchronizing 4 GB of data? By synchronizing I mean keeping all data on their server with automatic upload when files are changed. I am happy with Dropbox, but for now there is only 2GB free.

Comment: Well, there isn't much else besides dropbox that has more than 1GB or so. You could try and get people to sign up with the referral link, that can get you up to 8GB free (For a total of 10GB) - that's what I've done. That, and I did the Dropquest (At the time it was around). So to be honest, that's the only thing I've ever found. :)

Comment: 16 Gb, you can get up to 16Gb free now. You will only need 4 referrals to get the extra 2Gb. So it's quite feasible.

Comment: If 'free' is a hard requirement, please revise your question to indicate that more clearly.

Comment: @Javier: Didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: You can go to https://www.dropbox.com/free , and also win some free space (up to 8 GB) by inviting people https://www.dropbox.com/referrals.

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox as you already mention, or Ubuntu One, which is ~$3 USD per month for each additional 20G of storage (12 months for the price of 10 on annual billing)
https://one.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is [sparkle share](http://www.sparkleshare.org/), but it can be tricky and will make your files public unless you have a private server.
You can also use referals in dropbox to get extra space (I personally have about 8Gb).

Answer (score 0):

You can  register for a new gmail account and use [Gspace](http://www.getgspace.com/) to use the 7.3 GB(as of today) of space as free online storage.

Answer (score -1):

`rsync` is the best utility.

Try [`man rsync`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/rsync.1.html) to see the options.

Comment: Can you give more details such as a specific command-line?